# Help with Django Model relationship & admin screen

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My first time with Django and StackOverflow so could do with a little help.

A Platform has many Categories and a Category can belong to many Platforms. A product belongs to one Platform and one or more of that Platforms Categories.

So this is what I have so far for my Models:

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    platform = models.ForeignKey('Platform')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("platform", "category")
```

All looks ok when in shell but what I can't fully understand is how do I narrow down the Categories down based upon the Platform when I create a new Product? Ideally I would be able to get this working within the admin screens?

Does this Model look ok or can I do it better?

Comment: are you missing the relationship between product and category? You mention it in the question and in the unique_together but you have no category property on Product

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling what you're asking is that, when using the admin interface and creating a new `Product` model, you want to be able to select a `Platform`, *and then*, be able to select a category, where by the category options given are *only* those already associated with the chosen `Platform`.

That my friend is a bit more difficult than it would seem.  The reason why is that built into django there is no server "round trip" whereby after `Platform` has been selected the web app makes a trip to the server, gathers the options for `Category`, then displays it to you.  There isn't such an option by default (though I wouldn't be surprised if this eventually becomes included as part of the standard Django package).

However, there is a way to do this by implement it in javascript/ajax, which can be slightly challenging depending on your experience with either.

The good news is, as with most common tasks in Django, there's usually a community app either in development or already available to meet the need.  In this case it'd probably be worth checking out [django-ajax-filtered-field](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/).

Comment: Ah, ok I thought as much thanks for the link.

Probably need to rethink my model a bit then. I need to be able to get all categories that are within a platform. Also need to count the number of products that have that category.